# Python List sort algo, unepected last element of the list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, for-loop, timsort

The algorithm works as follow:

1. I find the minimum of a given list.
2. Then pop it and append it to another list.
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 until there is one element, in which case i simply append it to the other list and end the program.

**Issue**

The last element is always some random number which should be sorted long ago.

**Source Code**

```
lst=[randrange(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
lst2=[]
while True:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        min = 0
        for i in range(len(lst) -1):
                if min == 0:
                    min = lst[i]
                else:
                    if lst[i] < min:
                         min = lst[i]
        for j in range(len(lst) -1):
            if lst[j] == min:
                lst2.append(lst[j])
                lst.pop(j)
                break
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[0])
        break
lst = lst2
print(lst)
```

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)'s `end` argument is ***exclusive***. So it should just be `for i in range(len(lst)):`

Comment: By the way, [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) returns the popped element, so it can just be: `lst2.append(lst.pop(j))`

Comment: You can also use `index` to get the index without explicitly iterating and `min` to get the minimum value in the same manner - it'll give you far more readable code.

Comment: Yeah the range was the problem, thanks a lot! Thanks for the other tip too

Comment: @MatsLindh they can also just `lst.sort()`...

Comment: @ MatsLindh  I know about the min function but wanted to do it from scratch. Didnt know about index though, will check it out

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sure, but it's about selecting the correct abstraction for what you want to learn. If you want to implement a specific sorting algorithm, abstracting away "how to find the minimum value of a list" and "how to find the location of an element in the list" are perfectly fine.

Comment: @MatsLindh agreed. I was about to comment about the built-ins as well, but figured it's some kind of an exercise of the OP to do it all from scratch...

Comment: This will fail for a list of negative numbers. Replace `min = 0` with `min = None` and change the corresponding test accordingly. The posted answers did not fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has just one minor flaw. As @Tomerikoo pointed out already, there is just a little mistake at the iterators.
The correct code would look like this:

```
lst=[randrange(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
lst2=[]
while True:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        min = 0
        for i in range(len(lst)):
                if min == 0:
                    min = lst[i]
                else:
                    if lst[i] < min:
                         min = lst[i]
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[j] == min:
                lst2.append(lst[j])
                lst.pop(j)
                break
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[0])
        break
lst = lst2
print(lst)
```

There is a bit more elegant implementation, that iterates over the list items instead of just the indices.

```
lst=[randrange(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
lst2=[]
while True:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        min = 0
        for item in lst:
                if min == 0:
                    min = item
                else:
                    if item < min:
                         min = item
        for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
            if item == min:
                lst2.append(item)
                lst.pop(idx)
                break
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[0])
        break
lst = lst2
print(lst)
```

In the one case where you actually need an index an `enumerate` is your tool of choice. This improvement makes your code easier to read in general and utilizes one of the features of Python instead of, for example, C.

Comment: Worth noting that the `if/else` can also be removed by changing the loop condition to be `while len(lst) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `for i in range(len(lst) -1):` to `for i in range(len(lst)):`
2. You can improve the Algorithm by finding the index directly without loping twice as so:

```
from random import randrange


lst = [randrange(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
lst2 = []
while True:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        min = 0
        for i in range(len(lst)):  # FIND min value
                if not min:
                    min = lst[i]
                else:
                    if lst[i] < min:
                         min = lst[i]
        get_index = lst.index(min)  # Get index of Value
        min_value = lst.pop(get_index) # Pop min value
        lst2.append(min_value)  # Append min Value
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[0])
        break
lst = lst2
print(lst)
```

### EDIT

**@MatsLindh & @Tomerikoo Pointed out that `index` function internally runs a loop (so basically is the same) but just more readable**

Hence the following code would be much cleaner and with a better performance:

```
from random import randrange


lst = [randrange(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
lst2 = []
while True:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        min = 0
        idx = 0
        for i in range(len(lst)):  # FIND min value
                if not min:
                    min = lst[i]
                    idx = i
                else:
                    if lst[i] < min:
                        min = lst[i]
                        idx = i  #Store Index of min_value
        min_value = lst.pop(idx) # Pop min value
        lst2.append(min_value)  # Append min Value
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[0])
        break
lst = lst2
print(lst)
```

---

### Guides

- [index Function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

Comment: `index` will do the same loop internally; instead you can keep the value of `i` when you find a new min and pop that one.

Comment: It that so? so basically is just  Syntactic sugar?

Comment: ok makes sense, by the way I meant that using the index function won't make the time complexity any better? Because Than1 initially was running 2 for loops so I removed the second for loop and added the index function instead, but basically it does the same thing right?

Comment: Yes, under the hood it's still the same: looping until the first occurrence of the element and returning its index

Comment: Of course, it is still more readable to use `index` than a loop... So it is still preferable. But, again, in this case you can just save the matching `i` when you found the minimum and avoid the `index` loop altogether

Comment: Sure added the example, modified